# how to use user other than guest in rabbitmq for ELK?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash-configuration, rabbitmqctl

I am using `rabbitmq` for log queueing for ELK on ubuntu 14.04. I am able to communicate over rabbitmq guest user and everything is working fine. Then I create a new user using these commands :

```
rabbitmqctl add_user username pass
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags username administrator
```

Then I am not able to send messages and getting the below error. Any help ?

```
ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:53:53 ===
connection <0.1626.0>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no exchange 'my-exchange' in vhost '/'",
            'queue.bind'}

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:03 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1638.0> (192.168.1.25:36313 -> 192.168.1.24:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:03 ===
connection <0.1638.0>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no exchange 'my-exchange' in vhost '/'",
            'queue.bind'}

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:13 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1650.0> (192.168.1.25:36314 -> 192.168.1.24:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:13 ===
connection <0.1650.0>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no exchange 'my-exchange' in vhost '/'", 'queue.bind'}
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:23 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1662.0> (192.168.1.25:36315 -> 192.168.1.24:5672)
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2015::15:54:23 ===
connection <0.1662.0>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no exchange 'my-exchange' in vhost '/'",
            'queue.bind'}
```

Answer (score 2):

for create user run command :

```
  rabbitmqctl add_user username pass
  rabbitmqctl set_user_tags username administrator
  rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / username ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

also don't forget to add new user in `logstash`  file that you created under `/etc/logstash/conf.d/`

```
 user => "username"
 password  => "password"
```

EDIT :
in detail , if you are using logstash for shipping logs then you can create any file `/etc/logstash/conf.d/anyfile.conf` and put content  like below ( below is basic input file you can change it )

```
input {
    file {
        type => "logstash"
        path => ["/var/log/anylogfilepath"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     }
}

output {

  rabbitmq {
    exchange => "my-exchange"
    host => "my.domainname.com"
    exchange_type => "direct"
    key => "test"
    durable => true
    persistent => true
    workers => 4
    user => "username"
    password  => "password"


  }

  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

also don't forget to rabbitmq username and password entry as input at end ELK where you are analyzing and want to take input logs from rabbitmq.

Comment: thank you pl_rock for reply. i am trying your solution .